# Any difference between Alan Wake's PC and Xbox 360 versions?

Tags: version-differences, alan-wake

I've played and finished Alan Wake on Xbox 360 a long time ago, and the PC version of the game has been recently released. Is there any difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only differences between the two will be difference in graphic.

Quote from [official *Alan Wake* forum](http://forum.alanwake.com/showpost.php?p=139940&postcount=1) :

> There are a few differences - the engine is basically the same, as is the gameplay, but we've increased the engine quality settings on many areas including draw distance, shadow quality, post processing etc. We've of course included the Signal and The Writer with the game too.

You can see PC vs Xbox 360 screenshot comparison [here](http://www.lensoftruth.com/alan-wake-xbox-360-vs-pc-comparison-screens/).

And you can read even more about the graphical differences [here](http://www.dsogaming.com/news/alan-wake-graphical-differences-between-the-pc-and-the-x360-settings/).

Comment: The Collector's Edition (currently a free upgrade on Steam if you purchase the game, FYI!) also apparently has some in-game audio commentary that I don't believe was ever available for the XBox version.

Comment: "The only differences between the two will be difference in graphic" - I didn't find the original source, but I've seen several messages online claiming that difficulty settings were changed or to be exact renamed ("normal" to "easy", "hard" to "normal"). Remedy reportedly shared this information on [their forum](https://community.remedygames.com/).